# How to process only certain columns and ignore header and footer in delimited text file using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have an input text file called `text.txt`:

```
Header
Column1|Column2|Column3
C11|C12|C13
C21|C22|C23
C31|C32|C33
Footer
```

My output should be:

```
Column1|Column3
C11|C13
C21|C23
C31|C33
```

My command that I am currently using is

```
awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{NR > 1; OFS = "|"}{print $1, $3}' text.txt > text2.txt
```

Why isn't `NR > 1` making it such that Header is ignored as it is the first line?

Furthermore how would I ignore the last line?

Comment: Please replace the images with text (indent using the editor help function `{}`, to get proper formatting for code).

Comment: It makes your question better: If I would interested in answering and test it with the real input and check against the output, I don't want to have to type that stuff, I want to copy and paste. Apart from that a picture costs (at least) a thousand words (i.e. 2000 bytes).

Comment: Are you really using backquotes around your commandline? That will execute the result.

Comment: Can you post your output?

Comment: Please look at your post. You have backquotes around your pipeline. Can you why you need them there.

Comment: Also no im not using backquote

Comment: I see them in your post before `awk` and after `text2.txt`

Comment: Edited it just now

Comment: Yes and deleted the perfectly fine backquotes for markup around `NR > 1` .... %-)

Comment: Ok, put them back...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has been asked to replace images of text with actual text but refuses to do so.

Comment: @jasonwryan i'd like to agree, but i don't think that's actually grounds for closure.  even if it is extremely annoying.

Comment: @cas it is either the height of selfishness, or outright help vampirism (probably both) and it has no place here. OP was asked and just ignored the very polite request. Screw them.

Comment: there, fixed.  and  -1 because i had to replace the images with text myself.  ordinarily, i wouldn't have done that but it was only a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F '|' -vOFS='|' '/^Header|^Footer/ {next} ; {print $1, $3}' text.txt
```

This skips lines matching `^Header` or `^Footer`, and prints columns 1 and 3 for all other lines.

The Field Separator (FS) and Output Field Separator (OFS) are both set to `|`.

Comment: BTW, you really should edit your question and replace those images with text.  Never post images in a question when plain text will do.  Text is searchable, copy-pastable, editable, and readable on any screen size.  Images are not.  If you want good answers, make your question as convenient and useful as possible for readers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like this (`a.txt` contains the input):

```
 head --lines=-1 a.txt | tail --lines=+2 | awk -F "|" '{print $1"|"$2}'
```

`head --lines=-1` prints all but the last line
`tail --lines=+2` prints all but starts at the second line
`awk -F "|" '{print $1"|"$3}'` takes the first and third column

The result is:

```
Column1|Column3
C11|C13
C21|C23
C31|C33
```

Comment: This is a viable solution but is there a way to implement NR instead to not process header and footer?

Comment: I'm no `awk` expert. But what about `awk -F"|" '{if (NR>1 ) { print $1"|"$3}}' a.txt`? This skips the first line `Header` but the last line `Footer` is still processed...

Comment: I just started using awk today, but essentially I thought by using BEGIN I could indicate to unix to skip the processing of header...